# Reaction Roles System For NodeJS Discord Bot

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js, emoji

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please be nice and help me out if I do anything wrong!

I have done a lot of searching and can't find out how to do discord.js reaction roles. My biggest problem is the emojis. I want a user to run a command like this to add a reaction role to a message:
[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4PEr.png)

The problem is that I am only able to get the emoji ID from an emoji in a discord message but discord.js requires a actual emoji when checking if a reaction is the correct emoji before giving the role. I am storing the reaction roles in a mysql db.
I want the code to work with both default and custom emojis.
Is there something I am missing or is it just not possible to do this with discord.js?

here is some of my code
Check reactions:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("reaction added! emoji: " + reaction.emoji.name + " message: " + reaction.message.id + " user: " + reaction.message.guild.member(user).id);
  db.getrrConfs();
  for (var i = 0; i < rrConfs.length; i++) {
    if (user && !user.bot && reaction.message.channel.guild && reaction.message.id == rrConfs[i]['message_id']){
      console.log(client.emojis.cache.get(rrConfs[i]['emoji']).name);
      if (reaction.emoji.name == client.emojis.cache.get(rrConfs[i]['emoji']).name) { //this does not work. it requires the actual emoji not the emoji id that is stored in the db
        reaction.message.guild.member(user).roles.add(rrConfs[i]['role_id']).catch(console.error);
      }
    }
  }
```

Set new reaction role:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.host,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      database: config.database
});
let role = receivedMessage.mentions.roles.first();
let server = receivedMessage.guild.id;
let message = arguments[2];
let emoji = arguments[3];
if(emoji && role && server && message){
  console.log(server);
  con.connect();
  con.query("INSERT INTO `sudo_reaction_roles_configs`(`server_id`, `message_id`, `emoji`, `role_id`) VALUES ('" + server + "','" + message + "','" + emoji + "','" + role + "')", (error, results, fields) => {
    console.log(error);
    receivedMessage.channel.send("Set Reaction Role!");
  });
  con.end();
}
else{
  console.log("ERROR");
}
```